# Amazon S3 as a mount on Heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, liferay

I am new to Heroku , just wanted to understand if there is a way to have an Amazon S3 Bucket as a mount on heroku for my Liferay application to use.
I already have my liferay app deployed on heroku which is also connected to postgres.

My aim is to keep certain static configuration files on S3 and write into LOG files on S3.

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363914/mount-s3-folder-under-heroku-app
Very interesting qusetion though. I've been working with Heroku a while now, and I think this isn't possible... which sucks, because that's how assets should be handled... not with layers over layers of http.